# Not able to store file in database

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I'm not able to store a `file` in `database`

```
       <?php
class Manoj_Imgupload_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function IndexAction() {

      $this->loadLayout();   
      $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Image Upload"));
            $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");
      $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("home", array(
                "label" => $this->__("Home Page"),
                "title" => $this->__("Home Page"),
                "link"  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
           ));

      $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("image upload", array(
                "label" => $this->__("Image Upload"),
                "title" => $this->__("Image Upload")
           ));

      $this->renderLayout(); 

    }

    public function uplaodmeAction(){
                $img = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('img');
          if(isset($_FILES['img']['name'])) {

  try {

$uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('img');

    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // or pdf or anything

 $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

 $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

  $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') ;

 $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['img']['name']);

 $data['img'] =$path. $_FILES['img']['name'];
       $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                $connectionWrite = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_write');
                $query = "insert into imguplaod "
                                     . "(img) values "
                                     . "(:img)";

                $binds = array('img'=> $img);
                $connectionWrite->query($query, $binds);

  }catch(Exception $e) {



  }

}



                $this->_redirectReferer();
    }
}
```

**My form**

```
<form id="Upload" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('imgupload/index/uploadme') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

     <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />


    <h1> Upload form </h1> 

    <p><input id ="img" type="hidden" name="img" value=""></p> 

    <p>
        <label for="file">File to upload:</label>
        <input id="img" type="file" name="img"> 
    </p> 

    <p> 

        <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload me!"> 
    </p> 

</form>
```

**Database Table**

```
create table imguplaod(imguplaod_id int not null auto_increment, img varchar(100), primary key(imguplaod_id));
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Manoj_Imgupload>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Manoj_Imgupload>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <imgupload>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Manoj_Imgupload</module>
            <frontName>imgupload</frontName>
          </args>
      </imgupload>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <imgupload>
              <file>imgupload.xml</file>
            </imgupload>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <imgupload>
        <class>Manoj_Imgupload_Helper</class>
      </imgupload>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <imgupload>
        <class>Manoj_Imgupload_Block</class>
      </imgupload>
    </blocks>
    <resources>
      <imgupload_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Manoj_Imgupload</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </imgupload_setup>
      <imgupload_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </imgupload_write>
      <imgupload_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </imgupload_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

I also need to store the Media folder. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` that are required to post the file

```
<form id="Upload" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('imgupload/index/uploadme') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to get the file name add this code

```
 echo $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

you method name will be `uplaodmeAction`

spelling mistake change  `action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('imgupload/index/uploadme') ?>"`  to  `action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('imgupload/index/uplaodme') ?>"`

Comment: No luck sama 404

Comment: what is your module name

Comment: Mymodule/Imgupload

Comment: make sure your controller name is correct and also path too

Comment: Check my updated question i update my full controller

Comment: updated the answer ...

Comment: I changed Everythig Still same problem  where to use this echo $_FILES['file']['name'];

Comment: `''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('img');` in this code place

Comment: Can you please give me synatx what is file and name in that

Comment: this is correct syntax i gave to you. `$_FILES['file']['name'];` `file` is your field name.

Comment: $img = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('img');
                $_FILES['img']['name']; is it correct

Comment: `$img = $_FILES['img']['name'];` this is correct

Comment: Still same can you please check this Check this http://manoj.collagekingapp.com/imgupload

Comment: did you change `uplaodme` to `uplaodmeAction` and check if cache is enable then  disabled it

Comment: Yes i changed & cache is disabled only

Comment: place the updated code..

Comment: I update my full code can you please check it

Comment: spelling mistake change  `action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('imgupload/index/uploadme') ?>"`  to  `action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('imgupload/index/uplaodme') ?>"`

Comment: Yes thanks But value not store form only submited

Comment: `$data['img'] =$path. $_FILES['img']['name'];` change to `$img =$path. $_FILES['img']['name'];`

Answer (score 1):

1. Change your function name from **`uplaodme`** to **`uploadmeAction`**
2. You missed **`form_key`** to add in form. As of Magento 1.8 you need to include a form_key along with the post.

Add this **`form_key`** field in form

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

3. As @QaisarSatti said,  Add form attribute **`enctype="multipart/form-data"`**. With out this you can not upload images.

Hope this helps

Comment: No luck same it redirect to 404

Comment: If its 404 error. Then problem is in your controller. Put your `config.xml` file here

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: Also put your controller file.

Comment: i already add my controller public function uplaodme(){

Comment: Add controller class name and which it extends

Comment: Sorry i am not getting

Comment: Add your complete controller file here. Not only function. Add full controller file

Comment: Sorry class Mymodule_Imgupload_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

Comment: Is your module active from bootstrap file . Check '`app/etc/modules/Mymodule_Imgupload.xml`'

Comment: Boostrub???????

Comment: Yes, have you created this file? . Created this file. `app/etc/modules/Mymodule_Imgupload.xml`

Comment: Check i have updated my answer. Add `Action` to your function name

Comment: I changed Everythig Still same problem

Comment: Have you created this file `app/etc/modules/Mymodule_Imgupload.xml`?

Comment: Yes then only module work. My module is working fine but not uploading

Comment: 404 error gone? I can see that you have not put any image upload code there. check my third point as well

Comment: Check this http://manoj.collagekingapp.com/imgupload

Comment: Okay i can see that you have not added any image uploader code in your action method.

Comment: Can you please give that action metod

Comment: Here is uploader code :https://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/to-add-image-upload-field-in-magento-admin-form/

Comment: I update my full code can you please check it

Comment: What is problem now

Comment: Nothing it's working fine thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You named your action `uplaodme` in your controller, it should be `uploadmeAction`. You wrote it wrong, look at what you call in your phtml : `echo Mage::getUrl('imgupload/index/uploadme')`

Comment: I changed Everythig Still same problem